# Failed to connect to repository : Command "git ls-remote -h git@github.comcast.com:username/sidtest.git HEAD"

Tags: jenkins, github

Im trying to setup Github connection from Jenkins but get the above error.

Inorder to overcome this error, I tried changing to Jenkins user and run the git ls-remote command.

```
su -s /bin/bash jenkins
```

but when I run the command I get the following error -

```
bash-4.1$ git ls-remote -h git@github.comcast.com:username/sid.git HEAD
fatal: Cannot change to '/home/clduser/..': Permission denied
```

Comment: And...? You of course already investigated the permissions of `/home/clduser` so please tell us!

Comment: The jenkins user does not have a user profile or this directory .../home/jenkins..Im wondering should I create one or how to fix this?

Comment: Contact your GitHub Enterprise administrator.